# Add trailer in HttpWebRequest using c#

Tags: c#, node.js, httpwebrequest, transfer-encoding

I am trying to add trailer in HttpWebRequest header, but it is not appending that trailer after end of file data.

```
wreq.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
wreq.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
wreq.SendChunked = true;
//wreq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Te, "trailers");
wreq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Trailer, "Test");
wreq.Headers["Test"] = "the-value";

using (Stream POSTstream = wreq.GetRequestStream())
{
      //dataByte is file-data in byte[]
      POSTstream.Write(dataByte, 0, dataByte.Length); 
      POSTstream.Flush();
      //hashValue is trailer in byte[]
      POSTstream.Write(hashValue, 0, hashValue.Length);
      POSTstream.Flush();
      POSTstream.Close();
}
```

it should append this trailer "Test" @ EOF after blank chunk, but it doesn't append it. when i tried to add trailer programatically it consider it as file data rather than trailer.

Expected request:

```
POST <URL> HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Trailer: Test
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

5d    
File-data

0
Test: the-value
```

Actual request:

```
POST <URL> HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Trailer: Test
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

5d    
File-data

5A
Test: the-value
0
```

Why this Test trailer is not getting after blank chunk. This trailer will be used on server to identify end of file.
Please Help.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to add trailer after EOF. My request will look like this   `POST <URL> HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Trailer: Test
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

5FD
<File-data>

0
Test: 60096A89B4D92C1870C15806F6B5203E95543B`

Comment: And why you think that can be achieved by header? I think this is classical XY problem.

Comment: classical XY problem? do not get it.

Comment: Server should [understand EOF by receiving an empty chunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). No need for trailer header. Of course, if you're working with a flawed specification, you have to produce a flawed code. I've been there, done that.

Answer (score 2):

After more than a week research I came to know that Dotnet does not allow to add trailer in httprequest. To achieve above expected request I have used Node.js. For that,

First I have create app.js file which contains code for creating request with trailer and get response from server:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {hostname: 'ABC',port: 6688,path: 'XYZ/101/-3/test.file',method: 'POST',
headers: {'Content-type' : 'application/octet-stream','Trailer' : 'Test','Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}};
var fileContent =  fs.readFileSync('C:\\test.file');
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
res.setEncoding('utf8');
res.on('data', function (chunk) {fs.writeFile('C:\\response.xml', chunk);});});
req.on('error', function(e) {fs.writeFile('C:\\response.xml','Error: ' + e.message);});
var len = fileContent.length;
var bufSize = 4096;
for (var i = 0 ; i < len ; ) {
if (i+bufSize <len){req.write(fileContent.slice(i, i+bufSize));}
else{req.write(fileContent.slice(i,len));req.addTrailers({'Test': 'TESTTEST'});req.end();}i = i +bufSize;
}
```

And run this app.js file from dotnet as application and get the response:

```
//build app.js file content
var template = GetAppJSString();
var appjsfile = "C:\\app.js";
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(appjsfile))
{
    sw.Write(template);
    sw.Close();
}

var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    FileName = "C:\\Node.exe",
    Arguments = "\"" + appjsfile + "\"",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
};

try
{
    _nodeProcess.StartInfo = psi;
    _nodeProcess.Start();
    _nodeProcess.WaitForExit();

    //read and process response 
    var responseText = string.Empty;
    using (var sr = new StreamReader("C:\\response.xml"))
        {
            responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
        File.Delete("C:\\response.xml");
    // process response

}
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Hope this will help others and save their time.